# node.js files.upload.path is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working through the node beginner book and I'm at the final step. At this code:

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.parse(request,function(error,fields,files){
    fs.rename(files.upload.path,"/tmp/test.png",function(error){
        if(error){
            fs.unlink("/tmp/test.png");
            fs.rename(files.upload.path,"/tmp/test.png");
        }

    });
});
```

terminal tells me that files.upload is undefined - I'm not sure why - can anyone tell me?

Comment: Have you submitted files to your form? Do you have anything in the "error" variable?

Comment: You probably called your input type="file" differently than upload. Make sure these two match

Answer (score 1):

i have same issue too. I fixed by delete request.setEncoding("utf8") on server.js

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are on a windows machine. His examples are on Linux. I fixed it by changing the path to
"/Users/[USER]/AppData/Local/Temp/test.png" (in all places the other path is used)

Comment: I was actually searching to see how to change that default path for the download.